# How can I measure disk cache churn on Linux?

Tags: linux, cache, hard-drive, io, virtual-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get Cache Hit/Miss ratios for block devices in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/157612/is-there-a-way-to-get-cache-hit-miss-ratios-for-block-devices-in-linux)

I have a file server which serves out large (25GB-1TB+) files over the network from local storage.  I'm trying to decide whether adding more RAM for the disk cache would help performance given our access patterns, but I can't see how to measure disk cache churn.

Is it possible?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a *cache miss*, which makes this question a duplicate of [Is there a way to get Cache Hit/Miss ratios for block devices in Linux?](http://serverfault.com/q/157612/64706). Short answer is "no". Long answer is "maybe you can make one using `stap`, but it might be dangerous".

Comment: You can examine the contents of the filesystem cache using [the vmtouch tool](http://hoytech.com/vmtouch/).